# Is this confusion matrix correct?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to classify animal sounds. I'm using CNN for this purpose. I'm comparing the classes with each other, hence, some training will be done with 2 classes. Once I get the confusion matrix with these training, I encounter something like this:[image: confusion matrix]

As can be seen, it seems the model predicts everything correctly. On the other hand, when I raise the threshold from 0.5 to 0.8, I see that there are some misclassification. This is actually what I expected, but I confused that when I get the accuracy, precision, recall and f1 score, I see a value with lower than 1, and all are the same, as in the picture. However, I expect all of them as 1 because there is no misclassification. Am I wrong? Can you please explain? Thx in advance.

Note that my data has 2 class and each of which has 1200 records. I trained them with a CNN model.  20% of the data is used as test, rest of them are training.

Code is below:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (predictions > 0.5)
print(predictions.shape, y_pred.shape)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
cm(y_pred, y_test)
```

Comment: And how is this programming question?

Comment: + *and all are the same*, yes because you are using `micro` as the averaging method.

Comment: @buran you are right, this isn't a programming question, but I've no idea where to post an output of a programming language? Isn't stackoverflow a good choice?

Comment: You can try on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as *text*, *not* screenshots; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you computed confusion matrix between **prediction** and **itself**, instead of prediction and `y_test`.

It should be

```
cm(y_pred, y_test)
```